# Correct Error Message in Zod and React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, zod, libphonenumber

I want to validate a phone number. If it has a value then it should output "Invalid mobile number format". If it is blank, then it should output "Mobile number is required".

Currently, it always outputs as "Invalid mobile number format".

I'm using `Zod`, `react-hook-form` and `libphonenumber-js`

```js
import { isValidPhoneNumber } from "libphonenumber-js";

...

const schema = zod.object({
  firstName: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "First name is required.",
    })
    .nonempty("First name is required."),
  lastName: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "Last name is required.",
    })
    .nonempty("Last name is required."),
  contactNumber: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "Mobile number is required.",
    })
    .transform((value) => `+${value}`)
    .refine(isValidPhoneNumber, "Invalid mobile number format.")
    .transform((value) => value.slice(1)),
});

...

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="contactNumber"
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, ...props }) => (
    <StyledPhoneInput
      enableSearch
      enableTerritories
      specialLabel="Mobile number "
      inputProps={{
        ref,
        required: true,
        placeholder: "+84",
      }}
      country={"vn"}
      autoFormat
      field={field}
      muiProps={{ required: true, fullWidth: true }}
      {...props}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what constitutes a minimum valid phone number, but basically it seems you need to validate some minimum input on the `contactNumber` field. From what I can tell, specifying `required_error` prop only seems to require a *defined* value.

For example, if you had *just* `firstName: zod.string({ required_error: "First name is required." })` then the value `""` is accepted while `undefined` throws the error that `"First name is required."`. The `.nonempty` validator appears to coerce the string into a character array and assert that it is not empty.

You can assert the the `contactNumber` also has some minimal, non-zero, amount of input.

Example:

```js
contactNumber: zod
  .string({
    required_error: "Mobile number is required.",
  })
  .min(1, "Mobile number is required.")
  .transform((value) => `+${value}`)
  .refine(isValidPhoneNumber, "Invalid mobile number format.")
  .transform((value) => value.slice(1)),
```

[image: Edit correct-error-message-in-zod-and-react-hook-form]

```js
const schema = zod.object({
  firstName: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "First name is required.",
    })
    .nonempty("First name is required."),
  lastName: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "Last name is required.",
    })
    .nonempty("Last name is required."),
  contactNumber: zod
    .string({
      required_error: "Mobile number is required.",
    })
    .min(10, "Mobile number is too short.")
    .transform((value) => `+${value}`)
    .refine(isValidPhoneNumber, "Invalid mobile number format.")
    .transform((value) => value.slice(1)),
});
```

```js
schema.parse({
  firstName: "Norman",
  lastName: "Newman",
  contactNumber: undefined, // Number is required
});

schema.parse({
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Sacamano",
  contactNumber: "5555555", // Too short
});

schema.parse({
  firstName: "Cosmo",
  lastName: "Kramer",
  contactNumber: "2125555555", // Invalid format
});

const result = schema.parse({
  firstName: "Jerry",
  lastName: "Seinfeld",
  contactNumber: "12125555555", // Valid
});
```

Comment: Ah. Sorry I lack something in my question. I'm using react-phone-input-2. Will update my question soon. So it validates based on the country chosen

Comment: @Joseph Well, I appreciate the update. I also don't think your question was really about the phone number format validation, but that the "required error" was missing in the field validation when the input value is falsey, e.g. `""`. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. But some country have two digit area code some have one. So I wondering, how can we achieve displaying "Mobile number is required" vs "Invalid....". But will update my question soon for better understanding and debugging.

Comment: @Joseph From what I understand of the code, the `.min(1, "Mobile number is required.")` should cover the "is required" part, the rest would be for the format validation. `.min(1)` is effectively the same as `.nonempty()` but it's for string type values.